# How to modify mb_convert_case function for a locale language exception?

Tags: php, mb-convert-encoding

I convert titles to MB_CASE_TITLE case with:

```
$title_of_post_case = mb_convert_case($title_of_post, MB_CASE_TITLE);
```

However, there is an exception in our locale language: Lowercase of I letter is ı (not i).  So, KALDIRIMLAR word converts to Kaldirimlar instead of Kaldırımlar.

How can I solve this problem?